# lookbehind in a for loop

Tags: python, regex

How are you doing?

Am kinda stuck with this problem, I need to use a for loop to find a word that ends with 'ing' and is preceded by a tag that is IN, I come from a background of C and java and there its easy to do, but I cant yet grasp how to do it in python!!

I searched around and here is what I think i need to do:

```
for word, tag in list:
    if word.endswith('ing'):
       //use regular expression here which should look like this '(?<=\bIN\b)ing'
```

now ofcourse there are some problems there, first I the I need to look at the previous tag not word, the regular expression is probably is wrong and more importantly this just sounds too complicated, am I missing something here, is there a way to just use the index of the word ending with 'ing' to look at the tag behind it like I would have done using java for example??

Thank you in advance and sorry if its a silly question, its like my second time trying to write python and am still rusty with it =)

***EDIT***: more explanation on what I need to do, and an example here is what am trying to solve, sometimes pos_tag mistakes a VBG for a noun, so i need to write a method that given a tagged list (for example [('Cultivate', 'NNP'), ('peace', 'NN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('observing', 'NN'), ('justice', 'NN')] corrects this problem and returns [('Cultivate', 'NNP'), ('peace', 'NN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('observing', '**VBG**'), ('justice', 'NN')] ) notice how observing has changed

***EDIT2***: problem solved now, here is the solution def transform(li):
    for i in xrange(len(li)):
        if li[i][0].endswith('ing') and i > 0 and li[i-1][1]:
            li[i] = (li[i], 'VBG')

thank you guys all for your help =D appreciated it

Comment: What problem are you *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: It's not very clear what your input/output is. Why are you extracting 2 values from your list? Is it a list of tuples? Also you shouldn't use the variable name `list` as it overrides the builtin function list

Comment: Try showing a sample of the input and corresponding output.

Comment: here is what am trying to solve, sometimes pos_tag mistakes a VBG for a noun, so i need to write a method that given a tagged list (for example [('Cultivate', 'NNP'), ('peace', 'NN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('observing', 'NN'), ('justice', 'NN')]  corrects this problem and returns us [('Cultivate', 'NNP'), ('peace', 'NN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('observing', 'VBG'), ('justice', 'NN')] ) notice how observing has changed

Comment: Do you have any control on the list prior to this loop? ie, `for word, tag in list:` implies that `list` is comprised of alternating between a word of interest and the tag. Is `tag` the same as `word` or do you need to look at `tag` from the proceeding loop through? If you say your goal is easy in C or Java, write that down. Python can express the same algorithm as the C form. Then focus on the idiom after you have what you want working.

Comment: word and tag are different, i for is well as the name suggests...a word like from previous example, "cultivate", "peace" and tag is their tag like "NNP" or "NN", I need to look for a word that ends with ing, the look at the tag of the previous word, like observing, look at the tag of the previous word and check if its "IN" which is indeed the case

Comment: @AnH can you give a clear example of your syntax? You are clearly using a part-of-speech tagger which creates a list of alternating tags and tagged words and which seems to be arranged already as tuples - do you really need to use \b, etc.? It seems that you have already separated tag and tagged word

Comment: The syntax in "Edit 2" is kinda ugly. You can really express that more naturally in Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, sounds like you want this:

```
def transform(li):
    new_li = []
    prev_tag = None
    for word, tag in li:
        if word.endswith('ing') and prev_tag == 'NN':
            tag = 'VBG'
        new_li += [(word, tag)]
        prev_tag = tag
    return new_li
```

You can also do this in-place:

```
def transform(li):
    for i in xrange(len(li)):
        if li[i][0].endswith('ing') and i > 0 and li[i-1][1]:
            li[i] = (li[i], 'VBG')
```

Note that I renamed `list` to `li`. `list` is the type-name for a Python list and overriding it is a bad idea.

Comment: How does transform looks at the tag of the previous word, if am not mistaken, it just checks if word ends with ing and it's tag (not the one before it) is 'NN', I need to look at the previous tag not word's tag

Comment: @AnH Sorry, I didn't see your very last comment (which cleared it up) until now. I think I understood you this time?

Comment: gr8 =), if u still unsure of what I meant, feel free to ask and i will try my best to explain it again or give u another example, also thanks for the heads up about the li and overriding list =D

Comment: it looks about right, and really similar of what I would have done in java for example, I knew using regular expressions' lookbehind was not the correct way to solve this...I will try to run it now and see if would work =)

Comment: EDIT: the function works fine, it just doesnt let me assign values to the tuple, i.e. line li[i][i] = 'VGB' gives me an error...weird :S here is the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
    transform(xx)
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 4, in transform
    li[i][1] = 'VBG'
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @AnH Didn't realise they were tuples, which are immutable. Update should fix that.

Comment: works flawlessly now...thanks a bunch man =D =D...well that wasn't as hard as I expected, I knew RE werent the way. again thank you and all who helped out

Answer (score 1):

This does the change in place

```
for index,(word, _tag) in enumerate(li):
    if word.endswith('ing') and i > 0 and li[index-1][1] == 'IN':
        li[index] = word, 'VBG'
```

enumerate allows you to iterate over a list in a foreach fashion, but also get access to the current index. I quite like it, but I sometimes worry if I overuse it and should use something like `for i in xrange(10): ...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
previousWord = ""
previousTag = ""

for word, tag in list:
    if word.endswith('ing'):
       //use regular expression here which should look like this '(?<=\bIN\b)ing'
       //use previousWord and previousTag here
    previousWord = word
    previousTag = tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is somewhat driven by having immutable tuples as the data pairs in your list. The easiest way then is to create the new list you want in total:

```
li=[('Cultivate', 'NNP'), 
    ('peace', 'NN'), 
    ('by', 'IN'), 
    ('observing', 'NN'), 
    ('justice', 'NN')]

lnew=[]    

for word, tag in li:
    if word.endswith('ing') and tag == 'NN':
        tag='VBG'
    lnew.append((word,tag))

for word, tag in lnew:
    print word, tag
```

Somewhat wasteful if you have thousands or millions...

If this is your data and your format that you control, you may wish to consider using a dictionary instead of a list of tuples. Then you can loop the dictionary through more naturally and modify in place:

```
ld={'justice': 'NN', 'Cultivate': 'NNP', 'peace': 'NN', 
    'observing': 'NN', 'by': 'IN'}

for word, tag in ld.items():
    if word.endswith('ing') and tag == 'NN':
       ld[word]='VBG'
```

In large data sets, the dictionary approach is faster and more memory efficient. Consider that.

Comment: thanks man, but already figured out the answer, thanks anyways =)